# Question about question links

Tags: discussion, answers

Does the community encourage providing links to other questions in your answers?The purpose would be to back up the statements you make,but the answer would be in a way segmented,so it doesn't stand alone.To clarify my second sentence,I will exemplify by saying that the questions are independent of comments,so if the OP has to add any sensible information,he/she should not post it as a comment.I am sure about links to other sites(not SE) are permitted,but unsure if the same thing applies to linking other questions in answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not have to follow any links to understand a good answer. That said, links to pages explaining details or alternatives usually makes an answer *better* and more complete.

Therefore, it does not matter if you link to a question on EE.SE, an answer on EE.SE, an answer on any other website, or another external source. If your answer does not answer the question if the link goes away, it's not a good answer. Linking to a question can indeed be useful, for example to highlight differences between concepts.

It's worth mentioning that if the question can be answered by another question on EE.SE, it may very well be a *duplicate*, even if it's not a 100% match.